# Shell : workon not found

Tags: python, django, shell, virtualenvwrapper

I am writing a shell script that looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                         
workon pa                                                                    
python /home/project/manage.py command1            
python /home/project/manage.py command2
```

when I run the workon command in shell it runs fine ,
But In the shell script i get an error saying `workon command not found`
No clue whats going on here

**UPDATE:** `locate workon` fails, but it works fine in the shell

Comment: and what is workon pa?

Comment: The wrapper command for creating virtualenv

Comment: can workon be accessed from the command line?

Comment: yes, I have been using it everyday for my django project, works fine

Comment: Does it make a difference if you run `export PATH` before you run the script?

Comment: Do you run your script from cron?

Comment: 1. No it doesn't
2. I have made its entry in the crontab

Comment: perhaps `workon` is a shell function.  Try `type workon`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538628/virtualenvwrapper-functions-unavailable-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Welcome but I flag your question as duplicate, is it ok? So that they will know where to find the answer