# How can I check I'm not in a virtualenv before sourcing virtualenvwrapper commands in bash?

Tags: bash, virtualenvwrapper

I am sourcing virtualenvwrapper [so that I can use virtualenvwrapper functions in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538628/virtualenvwrapper-functions-unavailable-in-shell-scripts), as in the following simplified example:

Running `do_some ve_name branch_name` calls:

```
#! /bin/bash
# some script that takes parameters

source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper # the magic of sourcing
workon $1 # pick a venv
cd /some/project/path
git checkout $2 # pick a branch
python do_something.py
```

This works (and I don't mind dropping out of the virtual environment once it ends, in fact I prefer it). However, if I am *already in* a virtual environment I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/username/.virtualenvs/ve_name/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
```

So let's just assume that I will occassionally forget to deactivate my current virtualenv. I tried resolving this as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
# some advanced script that takes parameters

deactivate
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper # the magic of sourcing
workon $1 # pick a venv
...
```

But whether or not I am currently in a virtualenv, I get the following error (and it doesn't deactivate if I am accidentally in a virtualenv, which is the problem I want to solve):

```
/path/to/scripts/do_some: line 4: deactivate: command not found
```

So, how can I protect against already being in a virtualenv before sourcing virtualenvwrapper commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correct, the function `workon` is defined by the `virtualenvwrapper`.  You could check if the function is defined before attempting to `source` the wrapper.

Replace your `source` command with the following:

```
[[ $(type -t workon) == "function" ]] || source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: This didn't work - the workon function is defined even after typing `deactivate` to leave the virtualenv.  The solution by @theengineear worked, based on `VIRTUAL_ENV` env variable.

Answer (score 3):

You might also try using the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable as well. I found this to be a clearer solution after viewing this, so I thought I'd leave a note in case this is reaching others searching for similar solutions.

E.g.,

```
if [ ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ]
    then
        # do some stuff
fi
```

Here's the relevant portion of the `deactivate` function in the `activate` script:

```
# (inside deactivate function)
unset VIRTUAL_ENV
if [ ! "$1" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
# Self destruct!
    unset -f deactivate
fi
```

Here's how that gets set when you originally source the file:

```
# (runs when you source the activate file)
VIRTUAL_ENV="/path/to/venv/dir"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

This may not solve the original question (didn't test), but it's helpful for a large subset of cases where you just need to know if you're in a virtualenv or not.