# Why does using virtualenv commands in .sh file give "command not found"?

Tags: macos, bash, sh

I am trying to automate the removal and recreation of a virtualenv on a Mac (Mavericks).

I have a file `clean_venv.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start"
deactivate
rmvirtualenv test
mkvirtualenv test
```

This gives:

```
Start
./clean_venv.sh: line 3: deactivate: command not found
./clean_venv.sh: line 4: rmvirtualenv: command not found
./clean_venv.sh: line 5: mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

However, running the commands in the same location works fine. Why is this?

Comment: Your title says `sh` but the tags and the question say `bash`.  These are two different shells.  Bash is upwards-compatible with stock Bourne shell, but they are distinct; even where `/bin/sh` is a symlink to Bash, it causes Bash to run in a POSIX compatibility mode which changes its behavior in a number of ways.

Comment: I meant `.sh` - I have amended the title for clarity. Maybe a better way to phrase it though. Also, I found a workaround I've posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538628/virtualenvwrapper-functions-unavailable-in-shell-scripts) I've found this code to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
mkvirtualenv temp    # This makes sure I'm not on the test virtualenv,      
workon temp          # otherwise I can't delete it. deactivate doesn't
                     # work for some reason
rmvirtualenv test
mkvirtualenv test
workon test
rmvirtualenv temp
pip install -r requirements.txt;
```

This feels hacky, but it achieves the desired result. After updating `requirements.txt` one command can recreate the virtualenv from scratch. At the end I have one virtual env (`test`) and `temp` no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual environment is a feature of your current shell process.  Starting a new shell process (as in, running a shell script) creates a new process which does not inherit the virtual environment.

Given that, you actually don't need `deactivate`.  The other commands can be invoked once you make sure they are in your `PATH`, or, if they are functions, imported from the virtual environment's startup file(s).

Alternatively, define a function in your current shell, and use that instead.

```
clean_venv () {
    echo "Useless noise here."
    deactivate
    rmvirtualenv test
    mkvirtualenv test
}
```