# which mkvirtualenv returning false (1) but still executes

Tags: bash

Can someone explain to me why issuing the following commands (in the terminal)

```
which mkvirtualenv
echo "Return Value: $?"
mkvirtualenv test
deactivate
```

Succeeds with the following output

```
$Return Value: 1
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/xxxxxx/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python3
Not overwriting existing python script /home/xxxxxx/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python (you must use /home/xxxxxx/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python3)
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
(test)$
$
```

According to the `which` user manual it returns and exit code of `1` if

> if one or more specified commands is nonexistent or not executable

Therefore, a nonexistent or not executable `mkvirtualenv` command is being executed. I think the answer to this might explain why when I execute the same lines of code but in a bash script, like so

```
#!/bin/bash
which mkvirtualenv
echo "Return Value: $?"
mkvirtualenv test
deactivate
```

I instead get the following output

```
$ Return Value: 1
$ ./test.sh: line 5: mkvirtualenv: command not found
$ ./test.sh: line 6: deactivate: command not found
```

Can anyone tell me why it fails inside the script as it is causing one of my install files to fail.

**Edit:**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539449/654789), simply sourcing the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` file in every bash script is a hack way to get around this problem.

Comment: what shell does your terminal use ?

Comment: @0.sh `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run script as `/bin/bash` you are not using user context but the general context (I am lacking on proper terminology, bear with me) basically you lose access to all ENV variables that you may happen to have set in bashrc/profilerc/similar. And as it happens virtualenvwrapper asks you to set some stuff.

How to fix it?

Change `/bin/bash` into `/usr/bin/env bash` and script will behave exactly like if you did write this code in a shell.