# Activating VirtualEnv in remote machine and update python path

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I have two ubuntu machines one local and one on cloud.  The one on cloud has a virtualenv and all the programs are designed to run inside virtualenv.  I have ssh access and root access to the cloud machine.  I am trying to execute bash scripts / python scripts from the local machine.  However, I am stuck for 2 days only in getting the virtualenv activated, with no luck.  The following is from my latest trials:

Going by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538628/virtualenvwrapper-functions-unavailable-in-shell-scripts), I have create the .sh file.  This file works when executed from the cloud machine, however not when executed from my local machine.  I have tried various permutations and combinations and yet could not get it working.

My bashrc has these lines:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The latest configuration is in my bash script:

```
if (tty -s); then
    source /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/activate
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/models/research:/home/ubuntu/models/research/slim
fi
```

and my local script is as follows:

```
ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@12.34.56.789 "source .bashrc"
ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@12.34.56.789 "python /home/ubuntu/build_records.py"
```

I have tried innumerable combinations of the above, but couldn't get them working. I am ok even if the machine boots with venv as the default environment, which I tried through bash script....but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in one step:

```
ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@12.34.56.789 "
    source .bashrc && python /home/ubuntu/build_records.py"
```

This is necessary because all effects of `source .bashrc` disappear
when the shell and ssh client finish.

Comment: Thank you...I did try this combination yesterday and just now again just to be sure...but for some reason the sourcing of bashrc is not happening....I even tried with specifying the full path for bashrc...yet it did not help...not sure if I have to use any specific library or command before using source

Comment: Why do you think the remote shell doesn't source `.bashrc`?

Comment: I am not sure....have been testing with 100's of combinations and have even created a completely new ec2 setup....still source wouldn't just run.  For example..i have created an executable bash script in the cloud that contains `source /path/to/file`..and tried executed from local machine. Doesn't work.  However, calling a function such as `bash yetAnotherScript.sh` that doesn't call `source` works.

Comment: Finally!!!!! I got it working....the first few lines in bashrc triggers `if not running interactively, don't do anything`....I just disabled it and everything fell in place.....phew....still I am not sure what all would go wrong now....but for the time being I am able to execute the source commands remotely.  Thank you for your support